# How do I get all information regarding a ERC721 token

Tags: nft, erc-721

How do I fetch details about an NFT using JavaScript? Basically I want to get the owner detail minter detail and the NFT image of a particular smart contract and ID?
Is there any API or something?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few apis that return a json object of nft info, i have used these:

https://docs.opensea.io/reference/asset-object
https://howrare.is/api
https://api.magiceden.dev/